# Can SQL Server refuse a connection to one specific client, but allow access to every other client?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to learn SQL Server, so bear with my noobness, please.

I see the same errors repeatedly in the SQL Server log:

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
>   Login failed for user 'domain\username'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: ]

There were also many failed login attempts for the same client prior to this error starting.

I checked the connection string on the problem client and it's identical to the string used on other clients that successfully connect. Can SQL Server limit access to a specific IP/client, but continue to allow access to all other users?

Answer (score 3):

This has been discussed here by Aaron Bertrand:[Troubleshooting Error 18456](https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/14/troubleshooting-error-18456)

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
> Login failed for user ''.
> Reason: Failed to open the database specified in the login properties.

**Reason:**

> The database specified in the connection string, or selected in the Options > Connection Properties tab of the SSMS connection dialog, is no longer valid or online (it might be set to AutoClose or the user may simply not have permission).
>
> Note that this could also be a symptom of an orphaned login.  In this situation, you will need to synchronize the login and user information

Can SQL limit access to a specific IP/client, but continue to allow access to all other users?

> SQL will not and won't deny access to a specific client,it must fall into one of the above cases

Comment: Thank you for the rapid response and the link for Troubleshooting Error 18456.  It's some good information for future issues I know I will run into.